# Does my app with fabric crashlytics integration currently crashes if I don't link my app to firebase after march 2020?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

Does my app with fabric crashlytics integration crashes if I do not link my app to firebase after march 2020?

Comment: Please add some more information to your question as to why do you feel it will not work after March 2020. Give a link to the information that you have so that people can provide a better answer.

Comment: Please find link https://get.fabric.io/roadmap

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/OoDYm9Sqth4

Comment: The poster's questions is perfectly reasonable and does not require extra information - if no migration of an app from Crashlytics to Firebase occurs, will deployed apps function normally, even though they presumably will continue to try to post data to Crashlytics servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fabric/Firebaser here - even if you don't migrate before March 31st, 2020, your app **won't** crash due to the deprecated integration. You will no longer be able to migrate your app to Firebase or get crash reports from your users, but your app will function normally otherwise.

Comment: *firebaser here* Kevin is a support specialist for Firebase at Google. If you'd like to ask on a more official channel, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting. It should result in the same answer though, and might even be coming from Kevin there too. :)